# Even after adding JUnit to Eclipse's build path and using import static org.junit.Assert.*, still getting cannot be resolved to error

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am trying to follow test-driven development for one of the programs. I have added the JUnit library to my build path (by `Properties->Library->Add Library->Junit4`) but still I am getting this error:

> import static org.junit.Assert.* cannot be resolved to a type.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Please suggest what I can do

Comment: Does your source folder have a `module-info.java` file? If so, what are its contents? What are the contents of the project's `.classpath` file?

Comment: Yes there is a module-info.java file.In the content there is a simple definition of module as "module thrillioedit{  }",nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by performing the following steps:
1. Go to JRE System Library
2. Right Click and go to Properties.
3. Check your Environments

Answer (score 1):

You can try cleaning the whole project - project -> clean.

But you should not use IDE to manage your dependencies, like junit.
Use build systems like maven or gradle.

There are plenty of good tutorials for both, and after you have that set up, just add the junit dependency in the system configuration.

Comment: Not happening after cleaning the project

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `module-info.java` file, it is determining what is visible to your sources from the project's Classpath/Modulepath. Add `requires org.junit.jupiter.api;` to its contents, also making sure JUnit 5 is on the project's Java Build Path:

```
module thrillioedit {
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
}
```

Or more simply, just delete the `module-info.java` file because JUnit 4 is not modularized.

Comment: Deleting module-info.java worked wonders, been stumped on this one for a while.